# Why can't I float multiple posts next to each other when using -moz/webkit column width CSS?

Tags: css, css-float

On my blog that I am setting up, http://beerwhich.com/blogFun/index.html, I am using the column-width property to create a horizontal reading experience.

**The problem:** I cannot seem to get multiple posts to display horizontally next to each other despite floating both posts.

Any advice/knowledge would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: it seems like if I make the body's width: -moz-max-content it works but I am not sure if this is the best way?

I also noticed that I have to specify a width for each post or they overlap. I have a feeling this is an issue with using column width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sean; there is no problem with `column-width` property just give width to your `.container div`(parent div) which make space for `child` divs

For example:

```
.container {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px 0 0 100px;
    width: 4270px;
}
```

**EDIT:**

As you said that you don't want to specify width to your div's. So, may be you can do this

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.post {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 110px 0 0;
    white-space: normal;
}
.post .text {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -moz-column-width: 320px;
    height: 500px;
}
.column {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

check is example http://jsbin.com/oruyir/18  give `column-count:` property according to your text.

Comment: Thanks Sandeep :) Is there any way to not have to specify the width of both the posts and the container? If I have to do that with each article it could be a little horrible :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://css-tricks.com/166-how-to-create-a-horizontally-scrolling-site/ for a tutorial on how to make a horizontal layout work.

If you didn't need it to work in IE8, you could try using [CSS3's Flexible Box module](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/) and set `box-orient: horizontal` on your post items instead of floating them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `column-count` and `column-gap` instead and get a better result, mixing it in with `box-flex` you can achieve this design quite nicely.

Here's a little quick and dirty demo

http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/SvVGq/